# ThreadPool.SetMinThreads as Warm-Up strategy

Tags: azure, iis, threadpool, scalability

My web app faces huge CPU spikes. Not because of traffic increasing, but because of heavy load, such as reports going out. Some of these cause the CPU to go from a healthy 30% load to 100% for the next 2-10 min... Here i'll describe as if i had only 1 server, but i've seen up to 4 servers going crazy because the alignment of the stars made around 50 of my clients want a report at the same time... i'm hosted on azure and I use the auto-scale to handle these spikes. if the load goes north of 70% for more than 2 min, a new instance goes up.

The thing is, because server 1 is 100% backed-up, when it goes up, (i hope) the load balance will direct every new request to server 2 until server 1 can handle more again. Because of this (expected) behavior, I was wondering if I should raise the min number of threads so it can faster handle the requests that are coming.
My usual rate of requests is around 15/s, so thought i should start the pool with at least 50...

what you guys think?

**Edit 1 2017-07-13**
So far this is working fine... i'll try a higher setting and see what happens

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This strategy did prove itself very helpful and mitigated a lot of issues. Not all my problems are gone but the errors/timeouts decreased immensely.